# I want to add columns across filtered rows in power query

Tags: powerquery

I have a dataset in Excel which looks like this:

| Str_ID | Store_Name | Sales_Volume | Sales incl VAT | Sales ex VAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | A Staff Shop | 10000 | 329031 | 438708 |
| 34 | A Dotcom | 560000 | 18425736 | 24567648 |
| 75 | B Staff Shop | 45000 | 1480639.5 | 1974186 |
| 65 | B Dotcom | 780000 | 25664418 | 34219224 |
| 45 | C Staff Shop | 34500 | 1135156.95 | 1513542.6 |
| 595 | C Dotcom | 789230 | 25968113.61 | 34624151.48 |
| 9650 | D | 54053 | 1778511.264 | 2371348.352 |
| 2302 | E | 23453 | 771676.4043 | 1028901.872 |
| 242 | F | 23121 | 760752.5751 | 1014336.767 |

I want to remove the staff shops and add the corresponding column values to their corresponding dotcom stores. So, A Staff Shop's corresponding dotcom would be A dotcom. The output should look this:

| Str_ID | Store_Name | Sales_Volume | Sales incl VAT | Sales ex VAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | A Dotcom | 570000 | 18754767 | 25006356 |
| 65 | B Dotcom | 825000 | 27145057.5 | 36193410 |
| 595 | C Dotcom | 823730 | 27103270.56 | 36137694.08 |
| 9650 | D | 54053 | 1778511.264 | 2371348.352 |
| 2302 | E | 23453 | 771676.4043 | 1028901.872 |
| 242 | F | 23121 | 760752.5751 | 1014336.767 |

Please note the name of the stores are for illustration only and not single characters. Also, there are more than 30 columns in the dataset.

In Excel, I filtered the column for the staff shops and noted their names in a new tab, then manually searched each name and used subtotal and replaced the dotcom store values, deleting the staff shops.
The data is updated every month with new stores added. I am looking for a way to automate this, and any help would be appreciated. I also went to chatgpt with this, but the steps mentioned only lead to errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.Contains([Store_Name], "Staff Shop")), {"Store_Name"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"Staff Shop","Dotcom",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Store_Name"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value",{"Str_ID"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Store_Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Pivoted Column", {"Store_Name"}, #"Filtered Rows", {"Store_Name"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Str_ID"}, {"Str_ID"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Table1",Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in  #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

alternate version that might work faster for large data sets

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.Contains([Store_Name], "Staff Shop")), {"Store_Name"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"Staff Shop","Dotcom",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Store_Name"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value",{"Str_ID"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Store_Name"}, {{"data", each let 
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(_, {"Store_Name"}, "Attribute", "Value")
    in Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Other Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value", List.Sum)
, type table }}),
List = List.RemoveItems(List.Union(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),{"Store_Name"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", List,List),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Data", {"Store_Name"}, #"Filtered Rows", "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Str_ID"}, {"Str_ID"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Table1",Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in  #"Reordered Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks, @horseyride for replying. I tried the first method, and it worked. However, there is one issue, i.e., the merge step allocates the staff shop str_id to the dotcoms for half of the stores. Any way we could take care of that? Also, how do you merge the formatted table to the original table without writing it in code in the advanced editor?

Thanks, this was so helpful.

Comment: Thanks again @horseyride, just have one final query, I guess. I made the changes to the code and now, the dotcom centres have the store_id of the staff shops for all of them. I actually needed to go in the other direction and get the original dotcom store_ids for them. I'm sorry to be such a bother.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just rechecked the entire file. It pulls the original store_ids. But there are duplicate entries now, with one lot having the original str_ids and the other having the staff shop ids.

Comment: These duplicates come in during the expanded table1 query.

Comment: Thanks @horseyride, everything works perfectly now.